# Experiment:-$\sum_{j=1}^{2n+1}(j+1)\left\lfloor {j\cdot j!\over j+1} \right\rfloor$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, prime-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Experiment of Mathematica to $(1)$

> $$\sum_{j=1}^{2n+1}(j+1)\left\lfloor {j\cdot j!\over j+1} \right\rfloor \tag1$$
>   $\pi(n)$;[Prime-counting function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function)
>
> $\lfloor x \rfloor$;Floor function

We spotted a closed form given in term of Prime-counting function $\pi(n)$

We would like to know if it is correct for all values of $n\ge1$

> How can we show that $(1)=(2n+2)!-\pi(2n+1)-3$?

Greatly appreciated, if you can help.

Example

$n=1$

> $$\sum_{j=1}^{3}(j+1)\left\lfloor {j\cdot j!\over j+1} \right\rfloor=2\lfloor (1/2)\rfloor+3\lfloor (4/3)\rfloor+4\lfloor (18/4)\rfloor=0+3+16=19$$

$19=4!-\pi(3)-3=24-2-3$

where $\pi(3)=2$

Comment: Can you show me what you did in Mathematica (the code you used)? Interesting problem, btw!

Comment: I just used this http://www.wolframalpha.com/widget/widgetPopup.jsp?p=v&id=dfaf1b7d15e572ae5a1b2fa172ce8657&title=Math+Help+Boards%3A+Sum+Calculator&theme=blue

Comment: Oke, but I dont see in the output something that look like what you stated in your question!!

Comment: I think the calculator reset it self

Comment: I edited your question in the input button in the link, but I dont get a closed form.....!!

Comment: I show an example @Jan Eerlan, clear?

Comment: Yes, oke when it works for one value it will not perse work for every

Comment: It does not hold for $\text{n}=\frac{46}{5}$

Comment: @JanEerland : The OP only uses $n\in\mathbb{N}$ .

Answer (score 0):

We will use the fact that $\lfloor n+a\rfloor=n+\lfloor a\rfloor$ if $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
We can see that $j\cdot j!=(j+1)!-j!$.Dividing with $j+1$ yields $\frac{j\cdot j!}{j+1}=\frac{(j+1)!}{j+1}-\frac{j!}{j+1}$.
 So, the formula takes the form $$\sum_{j=1}^{2n+1}(j+1)\left\lfloor {j\cdot j!\over j+1} \right\rfloor=\sum_{j=1}^{2n+1}(j+1)\left\lfloor\frac{(j+1)!}{j+1}-\frac{j!}{j+1} \right\rfloor,$$ which is equal to $$\sum_{j=1}^{2n+1}(j+1)!-(j+1)\left\lfloor {j!\over j+1} \right\rfloor.$$
If $j+1$ is composite $>4$ then $j+1$ divides $j!$ so $\left\lfloor {j!\over j+1} \right\rfloor=\frac{j!}{j+1}$ which means that $(j+1)\left\lfloor {j!\over j+1} \right\rfloor=j!$.
On the other hand, if $j+1$ is prime then, from Wilson's theorem we know that $j!\equiv -1\pmod{j+1}$ which gives $\left\lfloor {j!\over j+1} \right\rfloor=\frac{j!+1}{j+1}$ and $(j+1)\left\lfloor {j!\over j+1} \right\rfloor=j!+1$.

(This '$1$' left is very important since it occurs for all the $\pi(2n+1)$ primes)

Combining all from above, you can rewrite your sum as $$\sum_{j=1}^{2n+1}(j+1)!-j!-\pi(2n+1)-2.$$ Note that the '$2$' comes because of the special composite $4$ we mentioned.

This sum is a telescoping one and it is equal to $$(2n+2)!-\pi(2n+1)-3.$$

Comment: If $j+1$ is prime, then $$\biggl\lfloor \frac{j!}{j+1}\biggr\rfloor = \frac{j!+1}{j+1} - 1.$$ But since we have the minus sign, we look at $$\biggl\lfloor -\frac{j!}{j+1}\biggr\rfloor = - \biggl\lceil \frac{j!}{j+1}\biggr\rceil.$$ Not sure whether that's a typo or a mistake (two, actually, which cancel) in your answer.

Comment: @DanielFischer I don,t get it.The remainder of $(p-1)!$ is $-1$ so $(p-1)!=kp-1$.Why we have an extra $ \lfloor \frac{j!}{j+1} \rfloor =\frac{j!+1}{j+1}-1$???There is no typo there I believe...

Comment: Let's take $j = 4$. Then $\frac{j!}{j+1} = \frac{24}{5} = 4 + \frac{4}{5}$, and so $5\bigl\lfloor\frac{4!}{5}\bigr\rfloor = 5\cdot 4 = 4! - 4$, not $4!+1$. However, we're actually looking at $$5\biggl\lfloor \frac{5!}{5} - \frac{4!}{5}\biggr\rfloor = 5\biggl(4! - \biggl\lceil \frac{4!}{5}\biggr\rceil\biggr),$$ and $\bigl\lceil \frac{j!}{j+1}\bigr\rceil = \frac{j!+1}{j+1}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer you are right.